# Doing a Send Transfer using monero-cli v0.14.0.2 with long payment id enabled, still getting errors on send

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, payment-id

Using the below command with long payment id enabled in monero cli v0.14.0.2 and I still get an error. What is wrong?

```
transfer 4xxxxxX 4bxxxxXX 2
```

> Error: amount is wrong: 4xxxX 4xxxxX, expected number from 0 to
>   18446744.073709551615

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user simply made a simple mistake. Therefore the question seems redundant and the user quickly found the mistake they made anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why is the format:

> transfer < **receiver_address** > < **amount** > < payment_id >

I had the payment id and amount swapped! Absolutely noob unfriendly...